# Do 見える - 見せる come from 見る?

Tags: grammar

I have not learnt much yet but I am interested in knowing it quickly. My questions are:

- Do 見える (to see, to be seen, to be visible, to appear) and  見せる (to show, to display) come from 見る (to look, to see, to watch, to take a look)?
- If yes, what kind of conjugation are used?

The term "conjugation" I mean here is like another conjugation, for example,

- 食べる - 食べない
- 書く - 書かない
- etc

Comment: The come from 見る yes. 見る－見えない。見せるー見せない。 Just the same as 食べる－食べない and 食べさせる－食べさせない or 書く－書けない and 書かせるー書かせない。 I am not quite sure of where you are having trouble. Is there a more in depth way you would like this explained?

Comment: They aren't conjugations; they're separate verbs. However, the meaning of 見える and 見せる seem like they resemble the potential (ability, i.e. "able to be seen" - visible) and causative (let/make, i.e. "let (someone) see" - show), respectively. The actual conjugation for these two forms isn't that far off from these either (would normally be 見れる and 見させる).

Comment: You're mixing up derivation and inflection.  They're *derived from* 見る historically but are now lexical words.  They aren't *inflectional forms of* 見る.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder 「見る－見えない」は誤りです。「食べる－食べない」に相当するのは「見る－見ない」、あるいは「見える－見えない」です。同様に「食べさせる－食べさせない」に相当するのも「見させる－見させない」で、「見せる－見せない」は別です。

Comment: @marasai 書いたときなんか変と思った。ありがとうございます。今度寝不足のままで書かないようにします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

見える is euphonic change (or slurring) from 見ゆる, which is a form of 見ゆ, which is a form of 見る（→み） combined with auxiliary verb ゆ.

見せる was a form of 見す, which is combination of aforementioned み and auxiliary verb す.

Comment: Isn't 見ゆ > 見える part of the whole shimo-nidan > shimo-ichidan shift? I wouldn't describe it as 'euphonic' at all.

Comment: I think that shift is exactly the consequence of euphonic change.

Comment: Really? I'd characterise it as a somewhat irregular result of the larger phenomenon of the rentaikei replacing the shuushikei.